# Erlang - Importing GPG Public Key

Tags: erlang, rsa, gnupg, public-key

I'm trying to do some public-key-related things in Erlang, and they require me to track public keys. According to [this page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/public_key/using_public_key.html#id61611), I should be able to import PEM format keys by using `file:read_file/1` and `public_key:decode_pem/1`. The thing is, when I try to import a GPG public key, I don't get a result.

I've got a file called `inaimathi.pubkey`with the following content:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.11 (GNU/Linux)
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=Zqph
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

which seems to be in the correct format, but the result I get is

```
1> {ok, GpgBin} = file:read("inaimathi.pubkey").
{ok,<<"-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\nVersion: GnuPG v1.4.11 (GNU/Linux)\n\nmQINBE9NBIQBEADMSzN6b0FaPP0rGiLDWKf"...>>}
2> public_key:pem_decode(GpgBin).
[]
```

Based on the documentation, I'd expect this to return an `RSAEntry` which I could then decode into a public key. Is there something special I need to do to import public keys through this mechanism? Are GPG keys actually valid PEM files? Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII-armored and PEM are very similar. You just need to change the BEGIN/END markers, strip the PGP headers and checksums (the checksum is the last line `=Zqph`), and add the PEM header. So, you have to change the `inaimathi.pubkey` to this file:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: It worked. Follow up question, if you know off hand, is there a way to get `gpg` to output public keys in PEM format directly, or does this mean I'll have to do some key-chopping in Erlang in order to accept pubkeys from GnuPG?

Answer (score 0):

The GPG and PGP tools implement OpenPGP Message Format as per [RFC4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html).

I did not have luck using any built-in Erlang/Elixir tools for decoding/decrypting data exported in PGP format. For that reason I've [partially implemented RFC4880](https://github.com/DivvyPayHQ/open_pgp) to an extend to be able to load private/public keys, decrypt encrypted message/file, and inflate compressed data. The Elixir lib is available [here](https://github.com/DivvyPayHQ/open_pgp). And also [this article](https://paveltyk.medium.com/openpgp-message-format-in-elixir-5719fb6fd9df) explains all the details of the implementation and walks thru some of the RFC4880 aspects.